# Bind nullable types unsupported

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-binding, nullable, blazor

I refer to [Blazor issue 1007](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1007).

I need to implement **nullable types binding** to use them in a database.

My sample works fine with all not-nullable types but if I define in my class a nullable I got the error:

> Error: System.ArgumentException: 'bind' does not accept values of type System.Nullable (.........)
>   To read and write this value type, wrap it in a property of type string with suitable getters and setters.

How can I implement such a wrapper?

Comment: What you mean by _"but if I define in my class a nullable"_?

Comment: In the class defining the db table fields. 
Following the answer of @Flores I define two properties: 

       private bool? dbNullableBool;

        public bool myNullableBool
        {
            get
            {
                return dbNullableBool == null ? false : dbNullableBool.Value;
            }
            set
            {
                dbNullableBool = value;
            }
        }
  
and now my Blazor app is happy ;-)

Comment: Check out the following https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13624 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputSelect.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
private bool realValue;

public string MyNullable
{
    get
    {
        return (string)realValue; //your logic for nulls here
    }
    set
    {
        realValue == bool.Parse(value); //your logic for nulls here
    }
}
```